# Creating a generic error object to indicate partial success of data retrieval in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

My question should be quite simple.

I have a Spring Boot REST API.

```
@GetMapping("/customer")
public Customer getCustomer() {
    return service.getCustomer()
}
```

My controller returns `List<Customer>` and works well. But now I want to return another object with the errors that can happen when gathering the customers. Let's say it's called `GenericErrorClass`

So to return this I need to create a class that groups List and GenericErrorClass and return that class, right?

that will work but now I have `Account`, `Product`, etc... I don't think it makes sence create a class for each one of them.

How can I build a custom object without creating classes and return that as json from the rest controller?

Comment: This is a bit more complex than you were thinking, since the fact that pulling back data like this can return *partial* success isn't exactly conventional.  What kinds of errors do you anticipate would happen in a partial success scenario, and what do you want to convey to the consumer of your end point when they receive that information? Or, do you want to log this information for your own private bugfixing purposes?

Comment: Spring already has a class that is more or less what you describe: [`org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html). Make your method return `ResponseEntity<Customer>` (or `ResponseEntity<List<Customer>>`) in your controller method; if an error occurs, then you can use the `ResponseEntity` object to set the appropriate HTTP status code (for example 404 Not Found instead of 200 OK).

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that.
Throw your exception, or let it escape from your call stack. Use `@ControllerAdvice` (or `@RestControllerAdvice`) with `@ExceptionHandler` instead.

You can extend the abstract class `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, and provide additional handling methods. On the long run that will matter for a clean application design.

If you intend to return the error with a status code of `200`, I'd like to understand why. I witness developers serving out responses for errored requests with `200` just because handling the HTTP error in another code branch at client side seems "difficult".

Comment: In principle you're probably correct, but it's unclear what the intent is behind the response.  I have to deal with 200s coming back from a service when all I get in the message body are errors, or partial successes.  Let's wait for the OP to clarify what they're actually looking for before we rush to answer.

Comment: @Makoto I rushed to answer because I see people handling errors the mentioned way (in the question) and it gets crazy frustrating. Why have error handling logic inside your Controller? ExceptionHandler(s) and ControllerAdvice(s) were made especially for this. You can create an appropriate response there, be it 200, 400, 500, whatever

Comment: Yes, but again I maintain that rushing to answer wasn't an appropriate choice here.  We need to *understand* what the problem is, not just pitch generic solutions.  Besides, if you *had* to return errors alongside successes, `@ControllerAdvice` would be wholly inappropriate.

Comment: @Makoto I understand, I'm sorry. I'll try to avoid doing it again.

Comment: I still think this is a good advice. If we need errors alongside partial success, then the original controller should still raise an appropriate exception which should *contain the successes* then a separate errorhandler can create an appropriate response (200 or 400) and it can insert the successes from the exception into the result.

Comment: @Selindek this is how I do it.

Answer (score -1):

Generally you would return error information when the request is not succeeded,  that coincides with a 4/5xx error code. Usually with Spring you manage this situation with exception handlers, as shown [here](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) where you can define a different response body. There is also another good practice: use envelopes to manage all responses, I will show you an example

```
{
   status: 200,
   message: 'user retrieved',
   result:
   [
      {foo1:"bar1"},
      .....
   ]
}
```

OR

```
{
   status: 400,
   message: 'bad request',
   error:
   {
     reason : "wrong field xxx in request"
   }
}
```

in this way clients can process the request and provide useful info to users. To do this you have to define a class that is used for all responses and should encapsulate the result or the error